# How to write a email pattern in angularjs for specific domain list

Tags: angularjs, email

I need to write a email pattern with ng-pattern for the following domain list: any domain that end with .com/.is.edu after @ or @com/@is.edu. For example, the email address for xxx@y.com or xxx@com should be valid, xxx@g.is.edu and xxx@is.edu should all be valid.

Comment: My current code using $scope.emailPattern = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.(?: |com|org|is.edu)$/i, but that only applies to xxx@g.com, and it will show invalid for xxx@com. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
/^\S+@\S*\.(com|id.edu)$/
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work, but I figured to use the following which makes it work (may not be perfect solutions):  /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@+(?: |[a-z0-9-]+\.com|com|[a-z0-9-]+\.org|org|[a-z0-9-]+\.is.edu|is.edu)$/i. so that anything after @ with org/com/is.edu will work, either xxx.is.edu or just is.edu after @